# Finding integration rule for f(x) using 4 points

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I need to find A,B,C s.t

(1) $\int_{x_0-2h}^{x_0} f(x) dx=Af(x_0-2h)+Bf(x_0)+C(f'(x_0)-f'(x_0-2h))+O(h^4)$

My first guess was using Simpson's rule, but I can't use $f(x_0-h)$.

Using Taylor I managed to evaluate $f(x_0-h)$ by

$f(x_0-h)=f(x_0)-f'(x_0)h + \frac{f''(\xi_1)h^2}{2}$
$f(x_0-h)=f(x_0-2h) + f'(x_0-2h)h + \frac{f''(\xi_2)h^2}{2}$

---

(2) $f'(x_0)-f'(x_0-2h) = f(x_0)+f(x_0-2h)-2f(x_0-h)+O(h^2)$

then I replaced $f'(x_0)-f'(x_0-2h)$ in (1) and tried to find A, B and C that match Simpson's rule. I got an error of $O(h^3)$

Comment: You have $f'(x_0 -2h)$ twice in the statement.  Is that correct?

Comment: Still waiting for a correction in the statement. Besides that, your error term $O(h^4)$ looks wrong, at least if you are considering functions without any other special properties. A simples test you can do is: if this formula holds it should work for a simple function, eg. take $x_0 = 2h$ and $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: you are right, it should be $C(f'(x_0)-f'(x_0-2h))$, I edited the formula. I forgot to say that $f\in C^{10}(\mathbb{R})$, that's all we know about $f(x)$